# !xdg-open <URL> doesn't open the website in my default browser

Tags: gvim, xdg

I am using gvim 7.3.401 on archlinux. The shell command `:!xdg-open http://www.vim.org` doesn't open my default browser with that link. In fact, it appears to do nothing.

**This works as expected** within terminal vim

How can I make it work in gvim too?

Comment: Both work fine for me on a Fedora 11 system, in that they both open that URL in Konqueror, although they both print an error message like this one: "<unknown program name>(25702)/ ClientApp::doIt: Creating ClientApp". Perhaps your environments differ between vim and gvim. Try executing ":!env > gvim_env" in gvim and ":!env > vim_env" in vim, then in the shell execute "vimdiff gvim_env vim_env" to see the differences. You may have to sort those files as well for the diff to make sense.

Comment: The only difference is vim_env has TERM=xterm, gvim_env TERM=dumb

Comment: It works on my debian squeeze box with gnome2, but not on my laptop with archlinux and gnome3

Comment: I'm afraid I'm stumped then. Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `:!xdg-open http://www.vim.org &`

I had the same issue until I saw how [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box/blob/cc784a55d26af74fea41bd1f162a40a2c43b5de7/ftplugin/latex-box/common.vim) does it.

Comment: I had a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15880689/152439. Since your answer helped me, feel free to answer my question, and I'll accept.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works and the original not?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `gvim` does spawn a new, dummy terminal for each command and it apparently kills it after the command returns. So the:

`:!xdg-open http://www.vim.org`

returns immediately and apparently(*) the `xdg-open` internal asynchronous call to `X` gets terminated, while making the call go to background (as suggested by ***sappjw***) doesn't:

`:!xdg-open http://www.vim.org &`

(*) - please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Your theory seems correct, since `:!xdg-open http://www.vim.org; sleep 2` also works.